# Get the number value of a texfield Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to have a textfield where the user can input a number and then set a label to that value. Is there any "texfield.value" or something that can fetch the value in numbers?
This is the only piece i heve done. should i put it here?:

```
- (IBAction)set:(id)sender;
```

{

}

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode, select the textField or textView and change the keyboard type to Numeric.

Then you can get the value of whatever the user inputs into that field by doing:

```
int value = [[textField.text] intValue];
```

Comment: where should i put it? it didnt work when i put it in a button action method.

Comment: Make sure you've connected your textField in Xcode. Does it have a @property? refer to it as self.textFieldName.text, other than that I can't help without seeing your code. Edit your answer and post your original code :)

Answer (score 2):

You can grab the integer value of a textfield using the following snippet.

```
[textField.text intValue]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: since im a beginner in programming I dont know where to put the snippet. Can you please help me?

Comment: Depends where you plan on using the number. You can do `label.text = [textField.stringValue intValue];`

Comment: it says "property stringValue not found on object of type UITextField"?

Comment: [textField stringValue] is only in Cocoa available. In Cocoa-Touch it is [textField text].

Answer (score 0):

You can get by **textfield.text** this will return the text value of that text field , now to convert it to number

NSNumber * mynumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[textfield. text] intValue]];

nslog(@"%@",mynumber);

Comment: it says "expected identifier"

Comment: did you put your textfield name

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of something I just used:

[self.phoneNumberTextField.text intValue];

You have to be careful with this one. Here are the steps to get this to work

1. In storyboard, select the textfield
2. Open the attributes tab for the textfield in Interface Builder
3. Change keyboard type to "Number Pad" (This guarantees that the user will only be able to enter ints into the textfield)
4. Now, in your code, type [self.myTextField.text intValue]; (set this equal to a local variable)

Now, as far as WHERE in the code you'll put this, it depends. If you're trying to log in a user, I'd recommend putting this in an IBAction like 'loginButtonPressed'. Or before you transition to a new screen in 'viewWillDisappear' or even 'prepareForSegue'.

Good luck!

Comment: Also, make sure your textfield in your storyboard is connected to your myTextField via an IBOutlet.

Answer (score 0):

This is from 3 years ago, I tried using that and didn't work and so I find this working for me

`int i = textfield.text.intValue;`